# VulkanSetupTest --> There is no identifier "vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vulkan

I followed the Vulkan Graphics Engine Setup at https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment and when I came to the section, where they test the setup with a program, I get shown an error in line 19: "vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);" : 
 *"The Identifier 'vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties' is undefined"* 
 I am pretty sure, that I followed all the steps correctly, but it seems, that it does not know the Vulkan Library (I thought about including it, but I couldn`t)

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_VULKAN
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#define GLM_FORCE_RADIANS
#define GLM_FORCE_DEPTH_ZERO_TO_ONE
#include <glm/vec4.hpp>
#include <glm/mat4x4.hpp>


#include <iostream>

int main() {
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Vulkan window", nullptr, nullptr);

    uint32_t extensionCount = 0;
    vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties(nullptr, &extensionCount, nullptr);
    std::cout << extensionCount << " extensions supported\n";

    glm::mat4 matrix;
    glm::vec4 vec;
    auto test = matrix * vec;

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where are you including a Vulkan header?

Comment: Works for me. Make sure you added `$(VULKAN_SDK)\Include` to your include paths. Also make sure you downloaded latest GLFW that actually supports Vulkan.

Comment: Thank you I forgot the includ Vulkan part.